# React js variable in render stays undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions as follows :

```
handleChangeInputStockName = async event => {
        const stockName = event.target.value

        this.setState({ stockName })
    }

handleChangeInputTotalQuantity = async event => {
        const totalQuantity = event.target.value

        this.setState({ totalQuantity })
    }
```

I have two components that control the above two functions

```
<InputText
 type="text"
 value={ totalQuantity }
 onChange={this.handleChangeInputTotalQuantity}
 />
```

and

```
<InputText
 type="text"
 value={ stockName }
 onChange={this.handleChangeInputStockName}
/>
```

In my render function both stockName and totalQuantity are always undefined, even though I can see changes being made to them in the InputText via the above two functions. I am able to see a state change however it goes back to undefined immediately. The render function is as follows :

```
render() {

        var { stockName, totalQuantity, show, close, children } = this.state

        console.log('stockName ====> ', stockName)           //undefined
        console.log('totalQuantity ====> ', totalQuantity)   //also undefined
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me out here. Thank you.

Here's a link to the sandbox for the Modal to which this code belongs. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-bush-rquid

Comment: Neither of your event handlers (as shown) should be an `async` function, as neither of them uses/needs to use `await`. It's not the problem you're asking about, but it's *a* problem. More about `async` functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (or, erm, in Chapter 9 of my new book :-D ).

Comment: Your state update looks fine (other than the `async` thing), your destructuring in `render` looks fine, and your using it as the `value` of `InputText` looks fine (but I don't know the details of the `InputText` RN comp), so it's not clear what's wrong above. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/), but not React Native. You may be able to replicate with `input` elements.

Comment: May I ask, why are you using `async` everywhere? I see your sandbox and you are using it with lifecycle methods as well. Try to remove those async functions because they return a promise.